# make: unable to locate user-defined header file that is included?

Tags: c++, makefile

When I run make, I get the following error:

`make: *** No rule to make target Menu.h', needed by Menu.o'.  Stop.`

Here is my Makefile:

```
PROG = sim
CURR_PATH = ~/Projects/restaurant/cpp/
CC = g++
CPPFLAGS = -g -v -Wall $(LOCAL_INCLUDES) -I$(BOOST_ROOT)
ODIR = ./bin
SDIR = ./src
LOCAL_INCLUDES = $(patsubst %,-I$(CURR_PATH)src/%,$(PKG_DIRS))
PKG_DIRS = $(shell ls $(SDIR))
FIND_SRC_FILES = $(notdir $(wildcard $(SDIR)/$(pkg)/*.cpp))
SRC_FILES = $(foreach pkg,$(PKG_DIRS),$(FIND_SRC_FILES))
OBJ_FILES = $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(SRC_FILES))
MAIN_OBJ = main.o

.PHONY : prog

prog : $(PROG)

all : ; $(info $$CPPFLAGS is [${CPPFLAGS}])@echo Hello world

$(PROG) : $(OBJ_FILES)
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $(PROG) $(MAIN_OBJ)
%.o : %.cpp
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
$(OBJ_FILES) : %.o : %.h
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $(patsubst %.h,%.cpp,$<) -o $@
```

BTW, in case you're wondering what LOCAL_INCLUDES looks like, the output for the 'all' recipe is the following:

```
$CPPFLAGS is [-g -v -Wall -I~/Projects/restaurant/cpp/src/concurrent -I~/Projects/restaurant/cpp/src/containers -I~/Projects/restaurant/cpp/src/data -I~/Projects/restaurant/cpp/src/loader -I~/Projects/restaurant/cpp/src/main -I~/Projects/restaurant/cpp/src/people -I~/Projects/restaurant/cpp/src/sim -I/usr/local/boost_1_72_0]
Hello world
```

Sorry for the single line output, I am unaware of how to format in a more readable fashion. But as you can see, the directory **data**, which contains `Menu.h`, is being properly included. But for some reason, make is unable to find it. What could possibly be going wrong here?

Let me know if you need more information.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The *compiler* knows how to find that header file. *Make* does not know how to find it, and Make is the one producing that error message.

I suggest you make this modification:

```
INCLUDE_DIRS = $(addprefix $(CURR_PATH)src/,$(PKG_DIRS))
LOCAL_INCLUDES = $(addprefix -I,$(INCLUDE_DIRS))

vpath %.h $(INCLUDE_DIRS)
```

(P.S. Your use of `CURR_PATH` and `.` is confusing, and `data/` is a terrible place to put header files.)

**EDIT:**
All right, let's take this in stages. Step 1, try this makefile:

```
OBJ_FILES = Menu.o

INCLUDE_DIRS = ~/Projects/restaurant/cpp/src/data

vpath %.h $(INCLUDE_DIRS)

Menu.o:

$(OBJ_FILES) : %.o : %.cpp %.h
    @echo building $@ from $^
```

and tell us what happens. (If it doesn't work, *tell us what happens.)*

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, but this actually did not work for me. Could it possibly have something to do with the order in which I define my variables? Forgive me, I am a make newbie trying my best to learn.

Comment: I appreciate the heads up on `CURR_PATH` and `data/`. I am still working on differentiating between which of my headers should be private and which should be public. Where else might you suggest I place my private header files?

Comment: Just figured it out. You were definitely on the right track with `vpath` but for some reason, the absolute path (i.e. `CURR_PATH`) was causing the issue. My reasoning comes from the bottom of page 20 in [this pdf](http://uploads.mitechie.com/books/Managing_Projects_with_GNU_Make_Third_Edition.pdf). A good read, I might add.

Answer (score 0):

As aforementioned, make's `vpath` did not like the absolute path that it was being given. See below for my modified Makefile:

```
PROG = sim
CURR_PATH = ~/Projects/restaurant/cpp/
CC = g++
CPPFLAGS = -g -v -Wall $(LOCAL_INCLUDES) -I$(BOOST_ROOT)
ODIR = bin

# vpath only needs SDIR and PKG_DIRS! 
SDIR = src

PKG_DIRS = $(shell ls $(SDIR))
INCLUDE_DIRS = $(addprefix $(CURR_PATH)src/,$(PKG_DIRS))
LOCAL_INCLUDES = $(addprefix -I,$(INCLUDE_DIRS))
FIND_SRC_FILES = $(notdir $(wildcard $(SDIR)/$(pkg)/*.cpp))
SRC_FILES = $(foreach pkg,$(PKG_DIRS),$(FIND_SRC_FILES))
OBJ_FILES = $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(SRC_FILES))
MAIN_OBJ = main.o

vpath %.h $(addprefix $(SDIR)/,$(PKG_DIRS))

.PHONY : all

prog : $(PROG)

all : ; $(info $$CPPFLAGS is [${CPPFLAGS}])@echo Hello world

$(PROG) : $(OBJ_FILES)
        $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $(PROG) $(MAIN_OBJ)
%.o : %.cpp
        $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
$(OBJ_FILES) : %.o : %.h
        $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $(patsubst %.h,%.cpp,$<) -o $@
```

I hope this helps other people that come across similar issues.